# Python script copying file issue

Tags: python-3.x, file-copying

I have problem with copyfile when using shutil library. I am using a different filename everytime I copy a file from one place to the other. That's why I put the variable name for filename as 'name1'. Anyone can help? Thanks!
The code I'm using is as below:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile
path1 = '/home/smc/sw_files'
path11 =  '/data/smc'
name1 = data
copyfile('path1 + '/' + name1', 'path11 + '/' + name1')
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python_gdrive_query.py", line 94, in <module>
copyfile('path1 + '/' + name1', 'path11 + '/' + name1')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: You have several misplaced quote characters. Your variables should not be surrounded by quotes. It should be `copyfile(path1 + '.' + name1, path11 + '/' + name1)` (Those are horrible variable names, BTW.)

Comment: Thanks Ken! it works with '/' instead of  '.' though..

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo on my part. Glad you could figure it out. :-)